# Can a returned value that can be null in java, be placed into a variable in kotlin which was declared as non null

Tags: java, android, kotlin, nullable

As a pretty new developer in Kotlin, I encounter for the first time a situation that I will be glad to get explanation for.
method *findViewById* of *View* can return null (this I know from knowledge as java developer but I will be glad to know if I can understand that a null value can be returned only according to method signature without the need to open android documentation )
**But** I'm surprised that the compiler doesn't prevent me from assign the return value into a **non - nullable View object**. Shouldn't it prevent this assignment? ASAIK, the following assignment won't compile:

```
var str1 : String? = "just a string"
var str2: String = str1
```

So what is the difference?

Comment: Have you read [java interop doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types)? Basically when you call java from kotlin you get a "platform type" which has relaxed nullability check. Also you might want to [upgrade to Android 11 SDK](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/03/handling-nullability-in-android-11-and.html) which includes more nullability annotations than before.

Comment: @Pawel, yes I read 30 minutes ago :) but I can't understand the definition of "platform type". Can you please explain me in simple words?

Comment: It has undefined nullability so you're free to assign it to either nullable or not-nullable field but in latter case you must be certain value is never actually a null or your program will crash at runtime. This only happens if you access java fields or methods that do not have any nullability annotations.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin's nullity checks are a figment of kotlinc. Once a class file has been produced, that question mark (or lack thereof) is just gone. The compiler has no clue. Yes, a method signature has this info (if you have a file with: `fun helloWorld(): String { return "Hello" }`, and compile it, and then write other code that calls `helloWorld()`, that code knows that the helloworld function has been declared to return a non-null string, even if you don't have the source file lying about) - but that is, as far as java-the-VM-executable is concerned, a comment.

In that way, it is **precisely** the same as generics. You can do this:

```
public void iWillMessYouUp(List<String> list) {
    List raw = list; // this generates a warning, but compiles.
    raw.add(5); // this compiles. I just added an Integer to a String list...
}

List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
iWillMessYouUp(myList);
for (Integer i : myList) System.out.println(i);
```

That code will throw a ClassCastException on the last line, which is funny, because there is no cast on that line. You'd have expected the `raw.add(5)` line to throw something, but that won't, because generics are a figment of javac. If javac doesn't stop you at compile time, java-the-vm certainly isn't going to do so either.

Same goes for those null types. It is not a nullcheck.

Note, however, that kotlin may inject explicit code with a nullcheck, I don't recall if it does that for the benefit of e.g. java code. i.e. this kotlin code:

```
fun say(in: String) {
    println(in)
}
```

gets translate to the pseudocode:

```
METHOD say(Ljava/lang/String;)V {
    if (in == null) throw new NullPointerException("in");
    java.lang.System.out.println(in);
}
```

A quick `javap` on what kotlinc spits out will show you whether it does this.

This gets us to nullity behaviour.

Turns out, there are 4 ways to do generics. To represent 'a list of numbers', there are 4 ways to do so:

```
List<Number> // invariant
List<? extends Number> // covariant
List<? super Number> // contravariant
List // raw
```

That last one is tricky: it allows everything, and intentionally (more or less) lets you break stuff. It doesn't have to be there, except it really does: There is code out there written before generics existed, and if the raw mode wasn't available, interacting with that legacy code would be excruciating.

Kotlin, as well as all the various annotation-based nullity systems for java (which are just as good as what kotlin does, really - same principle at work), need to deal with the fact that 95% of the community code out there in classfile form **does not contain any hint about nullity**. Thus, it needs to be treated as 'legacy'.

The way kotlin solves the legacy problem is very similar to how java solved the legacy problem with generics: **Anything goes**.

If you assign a value of legacy nullity to a non-null thing? 'Kay. Kotlin assumes you know what you are doing. It could inject an explicit nullcheck but that'd be a *LOT* of nullchecks everywhere, so many, that would have notable class size and performance impact. Pass null in a place of a legacy-null parameter? 'Kay. Apparently that's allright then, kotlin has no idea and defers to your code.

Incidentally, the fact that even without legacy there are 3 nullities and not 2 should tell you that kotlin's "Either things are nullable or they aren't" is oversimplified and means kotlin is incomplete on that front. And so it is: It is not possible to write a method that will take in a list of ?? nullity Strings and acts appropriately either way (so you can pass in a list of nullable strings, or non-nullable strings, your method does not care, whilst you still can both get (nullable) strings out, and add Xs, where X is either a known non-null string, or a (possibly) null string you get form that list. The concept of invariant, covariant, and contravariant tends to apply to all typing relations and tags, and nullity is a tag just as much as 'this list contains Strings' is one.

Comment: @rzwitsterloot, Thank you very much. But I'm apologize. You took a small question and made it huge. Why to talk on variant ,contravariant world? I just tried to understand two small issues and still after reading all your post I didn't understand nothing. I will approve you answer because the big  effort but unfortenatly I still don't understand the issue

Comment: @I still don't understand how to know if a method may return a null according to it's signature and still can't understand why a returned null can be assigned to a non-null variable. You gave an example with helloWorld method, so what is the different between the helloWorld and the findViewById method? and you also talked about 2 nullity and 3 three and I don't have a clue on what you are talking about

Comment: @DorVak because nullity is 'type tagging', and whilst it seems really really simple, it just isn't. I was hoping you had some idea on how complex java's generics are, but if you don't, yeah I can see how that is a bit much to process. Nevertheless, fact remains: type tags, even kotlin's seemingly simple nullity stuff, is incredibly complicated, especially in light of the fact that kotlin needs to interop with code that doesn't have this tagging.

Comment: The CRUCIAL aspect is that __in kotlin__, `var str1: String = "Hello"` means that the type of str1 is `@NonNull String`. It's _tagged_. And the type of `var str2 = String? = "Hello"` is also tagged: `@Nullable String`. But, a __java__ variable: `private String str1 = "Hello"` is __untagged__. Kotlin has no idea. It LOOKS the same ("String" in java, "String" in kotlin), but in java it's 'legacy nullity String', in kotlin it is 'non-null String', an ocean of difference.

Comment: I familiar with generics in java and understand the example you gave there. But I didn't find how it is related to the question I have asked. What's funny is that the generics was the only thing I understood in the answer :)

Comment: To put my answer in context, the first part explains why the __compile time__ info is important and the runtime aspect is irrelevant, and the second part explains, by drawing a parallel between generics and nullity, why it's actually really complicated, and that there is a difference between 'legacy-nullity String' and 'non-null String', same as `List` and `List<String>`.

Comment: Does Kotlin code always assumes that a java method will return exactly what he need? doesn't java have annotation to "mark" that the return type is from nullable or non-nullable type?

Comment: @DorVak java doesn't; nothing that is in the java language specification, and nothing that the core libraries use. There are MANY different third party takes, and kotlin ships with the ability to 'annotate externally': Take shipped code (such as the java core libs), and apply an external source of extra tags. Kotlin has this to some extent for java core libs, but .findViewById is android core, not java core, and apparently kotlin doesn't ship with 'external nullity type annotations' for android core.

Comment: you said that after compilation all annotation are deleted. Your words:"* Once a class file has been produced, that question mark (or lack thereof) is just gone* . So if i'm writing a new Kotlin class, that uses a method from a Kotlin class that was already compiled, how does the compiler still knows if the returned type and the parameters to function are nullable or not?

Comment: @DorVak the answer explains that a marker remains in the class file, but the virtual machine considers that a comment. kotlinc doesn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel better.  I think I need to open another question, since I see I don't understand the difference between java method and Kotlin method. I want to understand if some/all classes of Java was translated to Kotlin? Do you think people will understand the question?

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin you can not put a nullable value into a non nullable variable without null check.

This will compile

```
var str1 : String? = "just a string"
if(str1!=null){
    var str2: String = str1
}
```